# Is there a way to define a box around an equation in Pages using Latex?

Tags: pages, latex

I want to draw a box around formulae I am inserting into a page in Pages using latex.

Pages will not accept formulae inside text boxes and this would be a lame method anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a option for drawing a box around formulae inserted into a Pages document.  This is not super elegant but could be what the OP is looking for.

- From the Menu select **Insert > Equation...**
  Enter the desired LaTex or MathML into the dialog box.

  [image: Equation entry dialog]
- Insert a 'box'. Generally, a square shape sized, fill color removed or set to desired color, with a border of the desired width.
- Align both so that the equation appears in the center.

  - It may be good to group them together <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> so they can be moved or resized together.

  [image: Equation with box]

More info on LaTex or MathML for Pages: [Pages version 7.1 (5683) inserting equations using LaTex or MathML.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207569)

Comment: thanks!!!!! But apple has to improve that!

Comment: Agreed!  Apple could do much better

Comment: A new update for Pages was released today but there is no indication of what is new. Even their description of this update is bad. They say "add equations to documents using LaTex"... what is an irony.

Comment: I know, right. The link in my answer does not provide much new information that I can see.  Just what is and isn't supported. :/

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do in LaTeX: first `\usepackage{amsmath}`, and then

```
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\nabla E = \rho}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question about Pages. That doesn't work if you use "Insert Equation..." in Pages.

Comment: The Op specifically asks for Latex...

Comment: Oh, I see! I thought you created the equation with the like of [LaTeXIt](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) and then inserted it in Pages. But, well, frankly, that is still a better solution than the anemic LaTeX support of Pages…